# Linq intersect a child list of integers against a list of integers

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I have a list of users each of which contains a list of associated storefront IDs. I have a separate list of integers and I want to find where any storefront id of a user matches any of the integers in the separate list.

I'm expecting something like this:

```
clientUsers = clientUsers.Where(x => x.Storefronts.Intersect(allowedStorefrontIds));
```

I'm told the type arguments can't be inferred from the usage on the Where extension method.

Do you know how I should structure my linq in this case?

Comment: I think your lambda expression in your `Where` clause must evaluate to true, and I'm not sure it does here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a `.Any()` in the lambda to check  if the set-intersection contains any elements:

```
x => x.Storefronts.Intersect(allowedStorefrontIds).Any()
```

Personally, I would do something like this for efficiency:

```
var allowedIds = new HashSet<int>(allowedStorefrontIds);

var allowedUsers = clientUsers.Where(x => x.StoreFronts.Any(allowedIds.Contains));
```

Comment: +1, I didn't read the question and not your answer but I know in linq you are always right :)

Comment: @Saeed: Thanks, that's very kind. Not true though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Where expects a function that returns a boolean expression.  Intersect returns a list.  I think `clientUsers.Intersect(allowedStorefrontIds)` should return the list you're expecting, unless there is another list not mentioned in the code snippet.